# Compute $Var[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-E[X])^2]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference, descriptive-statistics

Let $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ be positive random variables in the range $[a, b]$ and $\sum_i^n X_i = 1$.

I want to compute

\begin{eqnarray}
Var[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-E[X])^2] 
&=& \frac{1}{n^2}Var[\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-E[X])^2]\\
&=& \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n Var[X_i^2] - 4Var[X_i E[X]] + Var[E[X]^2]\\
\end{eqnarray}

Here I got stuck. Are there any approximations I can use to go further or to at least estimate an upper bound for the variance?

Comment: You cannot replace the variance of a sum with the sum of variances because the $X_i$ are not independent.

Comment: Use the bilinearity of the covariance  and that $\mathbf{Var}(X) = \mathbf{Cov}(X, X).$

Comment: Hint: $E[X]$ is a constant

Comment: What distribution do the $X_i$ have? They are clearly not independent but perhaps they are exchangeable and identically distributed? Are they positive?

Comment: Your text has a $\frac1n$ which is not in your title.

Comment: Including the $\frac1n$ and assuming the $X_i$ are non-negative and identically distributed with $\sum X_i=1$, I suspect that $Var[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-E[X])^2]$ is bounded above by  $\dfrac{(n-1)^2}{4n^4}$ which has a maximum of $\dfrac1{64}$ when $n=2$.  For an example of that, consider $Y \sim \text{Bin}(2,\frac12)$ and $X_1=\frac12 Y$ and $X_2=\frac12(2-Y)$.

Comment: @Henry $X_i$ are positive and the output of a neural network. So I guess they are not iid. How do you derive $\frac{(n-1)^2}{4n^4}$ as an upper bound?

Comment: If they are not iid, then $E[X]$ may not be meaningful; perhaps you should have $E[X_i]$.  Though this may not make a difference if you use callculus42's result.

Comment: Suggestion: consider a very simple case first; try to figure out the quantity you are after; once you feel comfortable with the easy case, generalize. The simple case you could start with is $X_1$ being uniform on (0,1) and $X_2 = 1 - X_1$.

Answer (score 2):

I simplify the term as far I can think of

$$\frac{1}{n^2}Var[\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-E[X])^2]$$

Next you multiply out the square brackets and leaving variance opterator  still out of the brackets.

$$\frac{1}{n^2}Var[\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i^2-2E[X]X_i+E[X]^2)]$$

$$\frac{1}{n^2}Var[\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2-2E[X]\sum_{i=1}^n X_i+\sum_{i=1}^nE[X]^2)]$$

$E[X]^2$ is a constant and its variance is 0.

$$\frac{1}{n^2}Var[\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2-2E[X]\sum_{i=1}^n X_i+n\cdot E[X]^2)]$$

$$\frac{1}{n^2}[Var\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2\right)-4E[X]^2Var\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)]$$

Since $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=1$, we have a variance of a constant again.

$$\frac{1}{n^2}\cdot Var\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2\right)$$

To calculate/estimate it explicity further informations are needed.

Comment: +1 though  I am not sure the $\frac{1}{n^2}[Var\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2\right)-4E[X]^2Var\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)]$ line is necessary or helpful (independence  is not immediately obvious) or indeed the previous line.  You can can just say for the third expression that $E[X]$ and $\sum X_i$ are constant and make them disappear

Comment: $X_i$ are positive and possibly iid as they are the output of a neural network in my case.

Comment: @Samuel Probably the inequality $Var\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2\right)\leq Var\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)$ holds. But I'm not sure yet.

Comment: @callculus42 $Var\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right) = 0$ if $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i =1$

Comment: @Henry Arrghhh. Yes, I've oberlooked that.

Answer (score 1):

My thinking was that

- $\frac1n\sum (X_i-E[X_i])^2$ cannot be more than $\frac1n(1-\frac1n)^2+\frac{n-1}n(0-\frac1n)^2 = \frac{n-1}{n^2}$ or less than $0$ if $\sum X_i =1$ and each $X_i\ge 0$
- so its variance cannot exceed $\left(\frac12 \frac{n-1}{n^2}\right)^2 = \dfrac{(n-1)^2}{4n^4}$.
- To achieve this upper bound, have

  - probability $\frac12$ that all the $X_i=\frac1n$ and
  - probability $\frac12$ that one of the $X_i=1$ and the others $=0$.
- The maximum of the upper bound is $\frac1{64}$ when $n=2$.

  - For an example of that, consider $Y\sim \text{Bin}(2,\frac12)$ and $X_1=\frac12Y$ and $X_2=\frac12(2−Y)$.

Comment: If you instead look at $\frac1n\sum X_i^2$ following callculus42, then for my first bullet this cannot be more than $\frac1n$ or less than $\frac1{n^2}$ if $\sum X_i =1$ and each $X_i\ge 0$, and my other bullets remain as they were